# pymssql (python module) losing item when fetching data

Tags: python, file, pymssql

I have a database named "sina2013",and the columus is Title,Content
Now I want to use pymssql module to get the data.At the same time ,using the Title as the filename of a txt file,the Content as the content of the txt file.
The strange thing is the number of files is less than the items in database.
where is the error?
the code i have tried is:

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(...)  
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT Title,Content FROM sina2013')
count=len(cur.fetchall()) #Will return the right number :5913
for Title,Content in cur:
    filename=file(str(Title)+r'.txt',r'w')
    filename.write(Content )
    filename.close()
cur.close()
```

The number of txt file is less than it should be.
what is the reason?

Comment: dumb question i know - but are `Title` values unique?

Comment: Does it matter ? The same Title will be fetched once? Tommrow I will test that.

Comment: that is not how relational databases work. If you have multiple records with the same `Title` value, each record will be processed and you are going to end up overwriting the same file each time

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps changing your for loop into this:

```
# cursor fetchall() method returns all rows from a query
for Title,Content in cur.fetchall():
```

... will fix the issue?

Comment: I have tried code like yours ,but it does not work.The output number is still less than it should be.